How to take the partial derivative of a functional.
Given a function:
$$F(3x, 5xy) = 4(3x) + 5xy$$
And we want to know the answer of $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$:
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}  = \frac{\partial 3x}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial 3x} + \frac{\partial 5xy}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial F}{\partial 5xy} = 3(4+0) + 5y(0 + 1) = 12+5$$
But why don't we apply the chain rule to $\frac{\partial F}{\partial 3x}$ where we change the shape of the function to:
$$F=4(3x) + \frac{5}{3}(3x)(y)$$
$$\implies\frac{\partial F}{\partial 3x} = (4 + \frac{5}{3}y) \neq(4 + 0)$$
Applying the chain rule overcomplicates the question, and we could say that the answer is $(4)(3) + 5y = 12 + 5y$. Still, I want to know how the chain rule works, especially when I am dealing with a function that has position $(x)$ and velocity $(v)$ as its variables, where the velocity itself is dependent on the value of $(x)$.

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=3\frac{\partial F}{\partial(3 x)},.$ Why does that overcomplicate the question?

I meant that there is no need to apply the chain rule in this specific case, it is way easier to take the derivative wherever x is and consider y as a constant.

Your problem occurs when you treat $3x$ and $5xy$ as dependent variables (In your second calculation $4(3x) + 5xy=4(3x) + \frac{5}{3}(3x)(y)$). Partial derivatives (and chain rule) defined for independent variables.

The chain rule in your case is stated as follows: For differentiable real functions $F(a, b)$ that has real variables $a$ and $b$ and $a(x, y)$, $b(x, y)$ that has real variables $x$ and $y$,
$$\frac \partial {\partial x} F(a(x, y), b(x, y)) = \frac {\partial F} {\partial α} (a(x, y), b(x, y)) \,\frac {\partial a} {\partial x} (x, y) \; + \; \frac {\partial F} {\partial β} (a(x, y), b(x, y)) \,\frac {\partial b} {\partial x} (x, y)$$
In this statement, to calculate $\frac {\partial F} {\partial α} (a(x, y), b(x, y))$, you must calculate $\frac {\partial F} {\partial α} (α, β)$ first and then put $α=a(x,y), \; β=b(x,y)$.

Back to your problem, your first calculation is the case $F(α, β) = 4α + β, $ and $α=a(x), \quad β=b(x,y)$ where $a(x)=3x, \quad b(x, y)=5xy$. Then,
$$\frac {\partial F} {\partial α} (α, β) = 4$$
$$\frac {\partial F} {\partial β} (α, β) = 1$$
$$\frac {\partial a} {\partial x} (x) = 3$$
$$\frac {\partial b} {\partial x} (x, y) = 5y$$
By applying chain rule,
$$\frac {\partial} {\partial x} F(a(x), b(x,y)) = \frac {\partial F} {\partial α} (a(x), b(x, y)) \, \frac {\partial a}{\partial x} (x) + \frac {\partial F} {\partial β} (a(x), b(x, y)) \, \frac {\partial b}{\partial x} (x)$$
$$=4 \times 3 \; + \; 1 \times 5y = 5y+12$$

Second calculation is the case $F(α, β) = 4α + \frac 5 3 αβ$ and $α=a(x), \quad β=b(y)$ where $a(x) = 3x, \quad b(y) = y$. As we did above,
$$\frac {\partial F} {\partial α} (α, β) = 4 + \frac 5 3 β$$
$$\frac {\partial F} {\partial β} (α, β) = \frac 5 3 α$$
$$\frac {\partial a} {\partial x} (x) = 3$$
$$\frac {\partial b} {\partial x} (y) = 0$$
Hence,
$$\frac {\partial} {\partial x} F(a(x), b(y)) = (4 + \frac 5 3 b(y)) \times 
 3 \; + \; (\frac 5 3 a(x)) \times 0 = 5 y + 12$$
which is equal to the first case as we expected.

To summarize, when you apply the chain rule, you must recognize what $F(α, β)$ and $a(x,y), \;b(x,y)$ is in the statement of chain rule and make sure to put $α=a(x,y), \; β=b(x,y)$ after taking derivative. For this reason, you should treat not variables having variables like $3xy$ and $5y$, but first take variables and then put functions..
